Read-host in GUI textarea?
I am trying to write something between console style and GUI script in PowerShell. There will be a few buttons, labels etc and one big textarea with progress of script and user input.
My question is: Is there any possibility to set variable from textarea? There is read-host command in console script what save user input to variable. Is there any command, what works same in GUI? Just take characters after question in textarea and put them to variable.

Does this answer your question: Simple InputBox function?

The easiest way is to use separate controls - add a single-line text input control underneath the textarea control, then use that for user input
